# Custom Aggregate Function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been struggling with a problem with custom aggregate function in Pandas that I have not been able to figure it out. let's consider the following data frame:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(1, 5), 'weights':np.arange(1, 5)})
```

Now if, I want to calculate the the average of the `value` column using the `agg` in `Panadas`, it would be:

```py
df.agg({'value': 'mean'})
```

which results in a scaler value of 2.5 as shown in the following:
[image]

However, if I define the following custom `mean` function:

```py
def my_mean(vec):
    return np.mean(vec)
```

and use it in the following code:

```py
df.agg({'value': my_mean})
```

I would get the following result:

[image]

So, the question here is, what should I do to get the same result as default `mean` aggregate function. One more thing to note that, if I use the `mean` function as a method in the custom function (shown below), it works just fine, however, I would like to know how to use `np.mean` function in my custom function. Any help would be much appreciated!

```py
df my_mean2(vec):
   return vec.mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a callable as the aggregate function, if that callable is not one of the predefined callables like `np.mean`, `np.sum`, etc It'll treat it as a transform and acts like `df.apply()`.

The way around it is to let pandas know that your callable expects a vector of values. A crude way to do it is to have sth like:

```
def my_mean(vals):
    print(type(vals))
    try:
        vals.shape
    except:
        raise TypeError()

    return np.mean(vals)

>>> df.agg({'value': my_mean})
<class 'int'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
value    2.5
dtype: float64
```

You see, at first pandas tries to call the function on each row (`df.apply`), but `my_mean` raises a type error and in the second attempt it'll pass the whole column as a `Series` object. Comment the try...except part out and you'll see `my_mean` will be called on each row with an `int` argument.

---

more on the first part:

```
my_mean1 = np.mean
my_mean2 = lambda *args, **kwargs: np.mean(*args, **kwargs)

df.agg({'value': my_mean1})
df.agg({'value': my_mean2})
```

Although `my_mean2` and `np.mean` are essentially the same, since `my_mean2 is np.mean` evaluates to false, it'll go down the `df.apply` route while `my_mean1` will work as expected.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for such a complete and in-depth explanation!

Comment: @Ashkan No worries! Would you mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks

Comment: Just did! Thanks again:)